# Make a placeholder in input type text using label text in wordpress login

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this css problem in wordpress, What I want to do is just add a placeholder in input type which can achieve using placeholder attribute, but I don't know how this can be done in wordpress login.

This is my css..

```
<label for="user_login">Username<br>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20">
</label>
```

I find it hard to add a placeholder in wordpress login input type text, Anyway, as you can see there is a Username text, I was thinking on how can it be used as a placeholder for the input type text? If not possible, any suggestion/idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant html, not css. To add a placeholder text you simply add: placeholder="Your placeholder".

In your form it would be:

```
<label for="user_login">Username<br>

<input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" placeholder="Your Username" class="input" value="" size="20">

</label>
```

Javascript solution:

```
jQuery('#user_login').attr( 'placeholder', 'Username' );
JQuery('#user_pass').attr( 'placeholder', 'Password' );
```

That should work, if it doesn't try this from github https://gist.github.com/makeusabrew/985739

Comment: in wordpress login, I'm not sure how to add an attribute placeholder on input type.

Comment: Please make me understand, are you building your own login form or you want to modify the standard wordpress login form?

Comment: I'm modifying the default wordpress plugin, currently there is a text above the input text which indicate the usage of the textbox eg., Username, Password, Email. I'm trying to used those text as a placeholder to the textbox. If only I can add a placeholder attribute directly it would be easier.

Comment: Ah ok.. Got it, you have to use jQuery for that... I will modify the answer for you

Comment: I replace JQuery to $, since I used this jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

Comment: Sure mate it's the same :) glad I could help